# Memory leaks witht the "angular.module" getter?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

John Papa recommends chaining instead of creating variables while dealing with modules (see [the modules section](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#modules)) :

> avoid using a variable and instead use chaining with the getter syntax

He explains that :

> this produces more readable code and avoids variable collisions or
>   leaks.

I'm more comfortable with getting the module in a variable then set it:

```
var app = angular.module('mymodule');
app.config(...);
app.controller(...);
```

and less comfortable with the chaining :

```
angular.module('mymodule').config(...).controller(...);
```

As i'm coding using Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE), I'm pretty sure that variable collisions would never happen.

But, how about leaks ? Can someone explain or demonstrate how can an Angular app leak because I'm getting a module and storing it in a var ?

Answer (score 1):

Normally it won't cause memory leaks.

Here overridden module object leaks to global scope and cannot be garbage-collected.

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module('overridden', []);
</script>

<script>
  var overriddenApp = angular.module('overridden', []);
</script>
```

Comment: As stated, I code in an IIFE-ied mode :) When I read John Papa's statement, I thought that the memory leak would happen when appending components individually. You answer confirmed my thoughts :)